# Break point not working in Script Component if the Sytem.Net.Http DLL is added as reference for the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ssis, visual-studio-2017, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am finding very difficult to debug the code because the break-point is not working in Script component inside Data Flow Task.

If I run the code after inserting break-point, it doesn't stop at the break point and gets overridden.

I thought it was Visual Studio issue as I had downgraded to previous version. Then I tried it in my colleagues 2017 version, break point did not work in his system also.

Then we removed all the DLL one by one and commenting relevant code and checked whether break point is working or not.

Break point was working until we add `System.Net.Http` as a reference.

We don't know why break don't work if `System.Net.Http` referred as DLL in the code.

Comment: what version of http is being referenced?

Comment: what is your target framework?

Comment: Target Framework - .NET Framework 4.5; Version of `System.Net.Http ` is 4.0.0.0

Comment: Try run the package in 32-bit mode